# Regarding adding comments on posts on a page

Tags: php

I am making a website in which a user logs in and on the welcome page, he can add diiferent posts, like in facebook and those posts are shown on the same page using `POST`.

My question is that if i want to add comment boxes along with each post, what can be the code. Also please tell me how to manage the database when the comments will be added,, means what are the other tables that need to be created.

Right now I have 2 tables. one is the `users table(attributes:user_id, username)` and the other one is `posts table(attributes: username, post_content)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need another table. Everything else can be done parallel to how normal posts work.

Comment: please find 
[Adding comments](http://www.findsourcecode.com/php/how-to-create-comment-box-in-php-all-language-support/) and here also [And this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171997/php-mysql-how-to-create-a-comment-section-in-your-website)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need in each time when user posts something, to give a ID of that topic, main post. If you use *ajax*, then you can read it form some tag, where you writed it. But if you use **$_POST** , then you can use **type="hidden"** to give for e.x. id of topic.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can manage the comment boxes, as you manage with the Post content boxes.
For the database, I would suggest that you add an attribute like "post_ID" in your posts table to uniquely identify the posts.
Make this a Primary key.

Add another table for comments, which have attributes like "commentID"(Primary),"post_ID" which points to the post they are for, "Content" for the content of the comment, "User_ID" which points to the user who posted it.

Hope this helps !